# Bashrc unexpected EOF Error

Tags: bashrc

I am pretty new to all this so apologies if i am asking an easy question..

I need to update my .bashrc file which is a hidden file in home directory. İ opened it using gedit and overwrite it with my own file(cut-paste) and save and close .bashrc

Now when İ open the terminal it says:

> : command not found
>   : command not found
>   bash: /home/muhammadkashif/.bashrc: line 43: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Please help me with this.. A quick help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your script doesn't have 43 lines - there are only 42

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a mess,
Ive tried to tidy it up for you, this is the result...
***but I would reccomend editing your question and removing those ip addresses for your license exports... thats not very wise  to have those online....***

```
<pastebin link removed>
```

, I suspect your getting the command not found errors for something inside the scripts you are sourcing, in your terminal type

```
 bash -vvv
```

and pls paste the output to a comment here, thanks

Comment: its done now..thanks if possible please delete the file in your answer that you have attached since it has lıcense exports IPs. I didnt notice as I was frustrated..

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thats no problem, Im glad it helped, if you wish to pay back by upvoting my answer, it would be great for me. and I will delete the pastebin link completely, no problem. Glad it helped you